# How to know the string is decoded with which format ? can any one decode this string?

Tags: hash, decode, encode, urlencode

My generated string is "%2fxYdLLMoeO1s34oHAUBjSQ%3d%3d".

Now How can i know that this is decoded/Hashed and in which format ?

can any one decode this string?

I found it seems look like "ei" tag in google parameter.

When i try to decode /xYdLLMoeO1s34oHAUBjSQ== with base64 i get value like
(1) ,(xl@cI
(2) ,(xlߊ@cI
(3) ے,³(xيlكٹ@cI

Answer (score 0):

First encoding is clearly url %-encoding of `/xYdLLMoeO1s34oHAUBjSQ==`.

The next looks standard base64 of some data (based on `==` padding).

What actual data represent - your call: `FF 16 1D 2C B3 28 78 ED 6C DF 8A 07 01 40 63 49`

Comment: FF 16 1D 2C B3 28 78 ED 6C DF 8A 07 01 40 63 49 thi is ASCII value right??? but what is the meaning of this ?

Comment: When i try to decode /xYdLLMoeO1s34oHAUBjSQ== with base64 i get value like (1) ,(xl@cI (2) ,(xlߊ@cI (3) ے,³(xيlكٹ@cI

Comment: @HardikShah "this is ASCII value right" - I don't exactly know what *you* mean ASCII -It is just sequence of bytes. Indeed some of the bytes are in regular printable ASCII range `[0x20-0x7f]` but really no meaning beyond that. Like 42 - it is an answer, figuring the question for it is hard part and it is up to you.

Comment: OK. you told me that this is base64 encoded then why i not get proper String/value ?..question is how this "/xYdLLMoeO1s34oHAUBjSQ==" is generated ??

Comment: Question is how this "/xYdLLMoeO1s34oHAUBjSQ==" is generated ??

Comment: @HardikShah - clearly it is sequence of random bytes - http://www.xkcd.com/221/ ? I'm not sure what are you looking for... Are you pretending to have puzzle of some sort? Are you expecting people to randomly guess where you've obtained this string? Something else?

Comment: No. I know it's a difficult to know that the string is encrypted and encode in which format..i want to get knowledge that is that any way to crack this string...??

Comment: i am going to make an one application where any of string is decode/decrypt with all possible ways with actually in correct format.....